# Microsoft Excel how do I convert the first row into column and then sort the rest of the rows according to the first column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013

For Example I have this data:

```
+------------+--------+
| 01/11/2016 | Data 1 |
| 01/11/2016 | Data 2 |
| 01/11/2016 | Data 3 |
| 02/11/2016 | Data 4 |
| 03/11/2016 | Data 5 |
| 03/11/2016 | Data 6 |
+------------+--------+
```

Now I want to convert the first row into columns and how do I get this result ?:

```
+--------------------------------------+
| 01/11/2016 | 02/11/2016 | 03/11/2016 |
+------------+------------+------------+
| Data 1     | Data 4     | Data 5     |
| Data 2     |            | Data 6     |
| Data 3     |            |            |
+--------------------------------------+
```

Additional notes:

- I have tried using query builder and pivot table
- I have 365 dates(a year of date) and around 50-100 data per date
- I am using microsoft excel 2013

Thank you so much for all the helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a unique id (say with series fill) and labels (I have removed the `Data` since according to what you mentioned when asking this on SO you have numeric values):

[image: SU1144628 first example]

Pivot that:

[image: SU1144628 second example]

Copy the body of the PT and Paste Special..., Values (as lower part of image above).

HOME > Editing > Find & Select > Go To Special > Blanks, right-click, Delete..., Shift cells up. Tidy up.

Comment: You my friend, is a genius! I am so sorry for getting back late, have just tried your method, and it works, thank you very much for your kind helps, you have just saved me so much time. Again, thank you.